# Android SQLite error: variable number must be between ?1 and ?999

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm getting the following error when I am trying to update my table using a bigger number.

> SQLiteLog: (1) variable number must be between ?1 and ?999 
>   W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: variable number
>   must be between ?1 and ?999 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE
>   LoginTable SET image=?,alternate_contact=?,alternate_email=? WHERE
>   consumer_id=?74123

The code is:-

```
public static void updateProfileInfo(Context context, Consumer userModel, String consumerno) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseProvider.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LoginTable.Cols.ALTERNATE_EMAIL_ID, userModel.alternate_email != null ? userModel.alternate_email : "");
        values.put(LoginTable.Cols.PROFILE_IMAGE, userModel.profileImage != null ? userModel.profileImage : "");
        values.put(LoginTable.Cols.ALTERNATE_CONTACT_NO, userModel.alternateContact != null ? userModel.alternateContact : "");
        db.update(LoginTable.TABLE_NAME, values, LoginTable.Cols.CONSUMER_ID + "=?" + userModel.consumer_no, null);
        if (db.isOpen()) {
            db.close();
        }
}
```

where the consumer number is declared as VARCHAR

consumer number might be a number of length 1 to 999999999999

should I change the type to something else??

Comment: Please format your code correctly, using the code blocks. 

Also, the error is telling you exactly what's wrong. You have some restriction, meaning the maximum number (I'm assuming it means the ID) must be greater than 1 AND less than (or equal to) 999.

Please post some more example code from your project, e.g. how the database/table is created

Comment: `?74123` is the problem, and the reason for it is in the code that produced this SQL. Please post that code.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam for details on what `?NNN` means, btw - explicitly numbered parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
db.update(LoginTable.TABLE_NAME, values, LoginTable.Cols.CONSUMER_ID + "=?" + userModel.consumer_no, null);
```

is incorrect. 
You have 2 choices. 
The 1st is to concatenate the value passed to `LoginTable.Cols.CONSUMER_ID` like this:

```
db.update(LoginTable.TABLE_NAME, values, LoginTable.Cols.CONSUMER_ID + " = '" + userModel.consumer_no + "'", null);
```

if `userModel.consumer_no` is a string, or:

```
db.update(LoginTable.TABLE_NAME, values, LoginTable.Cols.CONSUMER_ID + " = " + userModel.consumer_no, null);
```

if `userModel.consumer_no` is an integer value. 
The 2nd choice is better and safer:

```
db.update(LoginTable.TABLE_NAME, values, LoginTable.Cols.CONSUMER_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(userModel.consumer_no) });
```

You can omit `String.valueOf()` if `userModel.consumer_no` is a string.
The error in your code is that you mixed somehow the above 2 ways of passing the argument `userModel.consumer_no` to the `update()` method.

Comment: Hey ...Thank you for your help...the code is working fine now

Comment: If it is working you may consider accepting the answer

Comment: Accept means to tick the checkmark left to my answer.

Comment: Fine no worries