# Is there any limitations for "WHERE IN" clause in sqlite on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqldelight

I'm getting such error sometimes when I querying a table by ids:

```
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: variable number must be between ?1 and ?999 (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , 
       while compiling: SELECT * FROM chat_ads WHERE _id IN (?1,?2,?3,?4,?5,?6,?7,?8,?9,?10,?11,?12,?13,?14,?15,?16,?17,?18,?19,?20,?21,?22,?23,?24,?25,?26,?27,?28,?29,?30,?31,?32,?33,?34,?35,?36,?37,?38,?39,?40,?41,?42,?43,?44,?45,?46,?47,?48,?49,?50,?51,?52,?53,?54,?55,?56,?57,?58,?59,?60,?61,?62,?63,?64,?65,?66,?67,?68,?69,?70,?71,?72,?73,?74,?75,?76,?77,?78,?79,?80,?81,?82,?83,?84,?85,?86,?87,?88,?89,?90,?91,?92,?93,?94,?95,?96,?97,?98,?99,?100,?101,?102,?103,?104,?105,?106,?107,?108,?109,?110,?111,?112,?113,?114,?115,?116,?117,?118,?119,?120,?121,?122,?123,?124,?125,?126,?127,?128,?129,?130,?131,?132,?133,?134,?135,?136,?137,?138,?139,?140,?141,?142,?143,?144,?145,?146,?147,?148,?149,?150,?151,?152,?153,?154,?155,?156,?157,?158,?159,?160,?161,?162,?163,?164,?165,?166,?167,?168,?169,?170,?171,?172,?173,?174,?175,?176,?177,?178,?179,?180,?181,?182,?183,?184,?185,?186,?187,?188,?189,?190,?191,?192,?193,?194,?195,?196,?197,?198,?199,?200,?201,?202,?203,?204,?205,?206,?207,?208,?209,?210,?211,?212,?213,?214,?215,?216,?217,?218,?219,?220,?221,?222,?223,?224,?225,?226,?227,?228,?229,?230,?231,?232,?233,?234,?235,?236,?237,?238,?239,?240,?241,?242,?243,?244,?245,?246,?247,?248,?249,?250,?251,?252,?253,?254,?255,?256,?257,?258,?259,?260,?261,?262,?263,?264,?265,?266,?267,?268,?269,?270,?271,?272,?273,?274,?275,?276,?277,?278,?279,?280,?281,?282,?283,?284,?285,?286,?287,?288,?289,?290,?291,?292,?293,?294,?295,?296,?297,?298,?299,?300,?301,?302,?303,?304,?305,?306,?307,?308,?309,?310,?311,?312,?313,?314,?315,?316,?317,?318,?319,?320,?321,?322,?323,?324,?325,?326,?327,?328,?329,?330,?331,?332,?333,?334,?335,?336,?337,?338,?339,?340,?341,?342,?343,?344,?345,?346,?347,?348,?349,?350,?351,?352,?353,?354,?355,?356,?357,?358,?359,?360,?361,?362,?363,?364,?365,?366,?367,?368,?369,?370,?371,?372,?373,?374,?375,?376,?377,?378,?379,?380,?381,?382,?383,?384,?385,?386,?387,?388,?389,?390,?391,?392,?393,?394,?395,?396,?397,?398,?399,?400,?401,?402,?403,?404,?405,?406,?407,?408,?409,?410,?411,?412,?413,?414,?415,?416,?417,?418,?419,?420,?421,?422,?423,?424,?425,?426,?427,?428,?429,?430,?431,?432,?433,?434,?435,?436,?437,?438,?439,?440,?441,?442,?443,?444,?445,?446,?447,?448,?449,?450,?451,?452,?453,?454,?455,?456,?457,?458,?459,?460,?461,?462,?463,?464,?465,?466,?467,?468,?469,?470,?471,?472,?473,?474,?475,?476,?477,?478,?479,?480,?481,?482,?483,?484,?485,?486,?487,?488,?489,?490,?491,?492,?493,?494,?495,?496,?497,?498,?499,?500,?501,?502,?503,?504,?505,?506,?507,?508,?509,?510,?511,?512,?513,?514,?515,?516,?517,?518,?519,?520,?521,?522,?523,?524,?525,?526,?527,?528,?529,?530,?531,?532,?533,?534,?535,?536,?537,?538,?539,?540,?541,?542,?543,?544,?545,?546,?547,?548,?549,?550,?551,?552,?553,?554,?555,?556,?557,?558,?559,?560,?561,?562,?563,?564,?565,?566,?567,?568,?569,?570,?571,?572,?573,?574,?575,?576,?577,?578,?579,?580,?581,?582,?583,?584,?585,?586,?587,?588,?589,?590,?591,?592,?593,?594,?595,?596,?597,?598,?599,?600,?601,?602,?603,?604,?605,?606,?607,?608,?609,?610,?611,?612,?613,?614,?615,?616,?617,?618,?619,?620,?621,?622,?623,?624,?625,?626,?627,?628,?629,?630,?631,?632,?633,?634,?635,?636,?637,?638,?639,?640,?641,?642,?643,?644,?645,?646,?647,?648,?649,?650,?651,?652,?653,?654,?655,?656,?657,?658,?659,?660,?661,?662,?663,?664,?665,?666,?667,?668,?669,?670,?671,?672,?673,?674,?675,?676,?677,?678,?679,?680,?681,?682,?683,?684,?685,?686,?687,?688,?689,?690,?691,?692,?693,?694,?695,?696,?697,?698,?699,?700,?701,?702,?703,?704,?705,?706,?707,?708,?709,?710,?711,?712,?713,?714,?715,?716,?717,?718,?719,?720,?721,?722,?723,?724,?725,?726,?727,?728,?729,?730,?731,?732,?733,?734,?735,?736,?737,?738,?739,?740,?741,?742,?743,?744,?745,?746,?747,?748,?749,?750,?751,?752,?753,?754,?755,?756,?757,?758,?759,?760,?761,?762,?763,?764,?765,?766,?767,?768,?769,?770,?771,?772,?773,?774,?775,?776,?777,?778,?779,?780,?781,?782,?783,?784,?785,?786,?787,?788,?789,?790,?791,?792,?793,?794,?795,?796,?797,?798,?799,?800,?801,?802,?803,?804,?805,?806,?807,?808,?809,?810,?811,?812,?813,?814,?815,?816,?817,?818,?819,?820,?821,?822,?823,?824,?825,?826,?827,?828,?829,?830,?831,?832,?833,?834,?835,?836,?837,?838,?839,?840,?841,?842,?843,?844,?845,?846,?847,?848,?849,?850,?851,?852,?853,?854,?855,?856,?857,?858,?859,?860,?861,?862,?863,?864,?865,?866,?867,?868,?869,?870,?871,?872,?873,?874,?875,?876,?877,?878,?879,?880,?881,?882,?883,?884,?885,?886,?887,?888,?889,?890,?891,?892,?893,?894,?895,?896,?897,?898,?899,?900,?901,?902,?903,?904,?905,?906,?907,?908,?909,?910,?911,?912,?913,?914,?915,?916,?917,?918,?919,?920,?921,?922,?923,?924,?925,?926,?927,?928,?929,?930,?931,?932,?933,?934,?935,?936,?937,?938,?939,?940,?941,?942,?943,?944,?945,?946,?947,?948,?949,?950,?951,?952,?953,?954,?955,?956,?957,?958,?959,?960,?961,?962,?963,?964,?965,?966,?967,?968,?969,?970,?971,?972,?973,?974,?975,?976,?977,?978,?979,?980,?981,?982,?983,?984,?985,?986,?987,?988,?989,?990,?991,?992,?993,?994,?995,?996,?997,?998,?999,?1000), (OS error - 11:Try again)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement + 948(SQLiteConnection.java:948)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare + 559(SQLiteConnection.java:559)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare + 603(SQLiteSession.java:603)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query + 46(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory + 1493(SQLiteDatabase.java:1493)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory + 1463(SQLiteDatabase.java:1463)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query + 161(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:161)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidQuery.executeQuery + 220(AndroidQuery.java:220)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidQuery.executeQuery + 195(AndroidQuery.java:195)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver$executeQuery$2.invoke + 132(AndroidSqliteDriver.java:132)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver$executeQuery$2.getOwner(AndroidSqliteDriver.java:132)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver$executeQuery$2.invoke + 19(AndroidSqliteDriver.java:19)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver.execute + 114(AndroidSqliteDriver.java:114)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver.executeQuery + 132(AndroidSqliteDriver.java:132)
       at classifieds.yalla.data.local.presentation.ChatAdsQueriesImpl$GetChatAds.execute + 688(ChatAdsQueriesImpl.java:688)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.Query.executeAsList + 113(Query.java:113)
```

It seems that limitation is 1000 items in the array which is not stated anywhere in the docs.

The table itself

```
CREATE TABLE chat_ads(
    _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

**UPDATE:**

What is an alternative solution if I need to query more than 1000 items by id? Currently, the relationship is that each `chat_ad` relates to many `chats`, so I'm just storing an id in the `chat` table, and then query however many items user need.

Comment: Put all those values in a temporary table and use it with `EXISTS` or `IN`.

Comment: Interesting idea and requires minimum modification! But I'm open to modifying schema.

Answer (score 1):

The [SQLite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) states:

> **Maximum Number Of Host Parameters In A Single SQL Statement**
>   SQLite allocates space to hold all host parameters between 1 and the largest host parameter number used. Hence, an SQL statement that contains a host parameter like ?1000000000 would require gigabytes of storage. This could easily overwhelm the resources of the host machine. To prevent excessive memory allocations, the maximum value of a host parameter number is **SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER**, which **defaults to 999**.

So you can set a higher value

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about all limits in official SQLite documentation [here](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

For Android version of SQLite you cannot change this limit beacuse it is configured at compile time. You can try to build your own SQLite version but probably the easiest solution will be to modify the query.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to set string value inside Integer (_id)

Please share your mode code.

I can share you similar issue where developer try to update integer value with string, and they got same error.

[Android SQLite error: variable number must be between ?1 and ?999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531217/android-sqlite-error-variable-number-must-be-between-1-and-999)

Comment: don't think so

`private inner class GetChatAds<out T : Any>(private val _id: Collection<Long>,
            mapper: (SqlCursor) -> T) : Query<T>(getChatAds, mapper) {
        override fun execute(): SqlCursor {
            val _idIndexes = createArguments(count = _id.size, offset = 1)
            return driver.executeQuery(null, """SELECT * FROM chat_ads WHERE _id IN $_idIndexes""",
                    _id.size) {
                _id.forEachIndexed { index, _id ->
                        bindLong(index + 1, _id)
                        }
            }
        }
    }
`

Comment: `protected fun createArguments(
    count: Int,
    offset: Int
  ): String {
    if (count == 0) return "()"

    return buildString(presizeArguments(count, offset)) {
      append("(?")
      append(offset)
      for (value in offset + 1 until offset + count) {
        append(",?")
        append(value)
      }
      append(')')
    }
  }
`

Comment: It worked just fine in production. The crash is happening in 1 from 100 000 cases